# Saving/ loading State of the checkbox using sharedpreferences

Tags: java, android, checkbox, sharedpreferences, state

I'm using checkbox with a Listview. I would like to save the state of them when the user clicks on the button b1 in order to load the proper configuration when he exits and starts again the application.

here is the code:

Main.java:

```
public class Main extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener{

 ListView apps;
 PackageManager packageManager;
 ArrayList <String> checkedValue;
 Button bt1;
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    bt1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    apps = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    packageManager = getPackageManager();
 final List <PackageInfo> packageList = packageManager
.getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA); // all apps in the phone
 final List <PackageInfo> packageList1 = packageManager
.getInstalledPackages(0);

try {
  packageList1.clear();
  for (int n = 0; n < packageList.size(); n++)
  {

   PackageInfo PackInfo = packageList.get(n);
   if (((PackInfo.applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) != 0) != true)
    //check weather it is system app or user installed app
   {
    try
    {

      packageList1.add(packageList.get(n)); // add in 2nd list if it is user installed app
       Collections.sort(packageList1,new Comparator <PackageInfo>()
         // this will sort App list on the basis of app name
       {
        public int compare(PackageInfo o1,PackageInfo o2)
        {
         return o1.applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString()
           .compareToIgnoreCase(o2.applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager())
               .toString());// compare and return sorted packagelist.
        }
       });


    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
  }
 } catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
 }
Listadapter Adapter = new Listadapter(this,packageList1, packageManager);
apps.setAdapter(Adapter);
apps.setOnItemClickListener(this);
bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  Toast.makeText(Main.this,"" + checkedValue,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }
});

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}


  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView arg0, View v, int position, long arg3) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
   TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
   cb.performClick();
   if (cb.isChecked()) {

  checkedValue.add(tv.getText().toString());
  } else if (!cb.isChecked()) {
  checkedValue.remove(tv.getText().toString());
 }

}
}
```

Listadapter.java

```
    public class Listadapter extends BaseAdapter{

     List <PackageInfo> packageList;
     Activity context;
     PackageManager packageManager;
     boolean[] itemChecked;

     public Listadapter(Activity context, List <PackageInfo> packageList,
       PackageManager packageManager) {
      super();
      this.context = context;
      this.packageList = packageList;
      this.packageManager = packageManager;
      itemChecked = new boolean[packageList.size()];
     }

     private class ViewHolder {
      TextView apkName;
      CheckBox ck1;
     }

     public int getCount() {
      return packageList.size();
     }

     public Object getItem(int position) {
      return packageList.get(position);
     }

     public long getItemId(int position) {
      return 0;
     }

     @Override
     public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      final ViewHolder holder;

      LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

      if (convertView == null) {
       convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
       holder = new ViewHolder();

       holder.apkName = (TextView) convertView
         .findViewById(R.id.textView1);
       holder.ck1 = (CheckBox) convertView
         .findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

       convertView.setTag(holder);

      } else {

       holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
      }

      PackageInfo packageInfo = (PackageInfo) getItem(position);

      Drawable appIcon = packageManager
        .getApplicationIcon(packageInfo.applicationInfo);
      String appName = packageManager.getApplicationLabel(
        packageInfo.applicationInfo).toString();
      appIcon.setBounds(0, 0, 40, 40);
      holder.apkName.setCompoundDrawables(appIcon, null, null, null);
      holder.apkName.setCompoundDrawablePadding(15);
      holder.apkName.setText(appName);
      holder.ck1.setChecked(false);

      if (itemChecked[position])
       holder.ck1.setChecked(true);
      else
       holder.ck1.setChecked(false);

      holder.ck1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (holder.ck1.isChecked())
         itemChecked[position] = true;
        else
         itemChecked[position] = false;
       }
      });

      return convertView;

     }



    }
```

I see that sharedpreferences can resolve my issue but I don't know how to use it. 
Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

To use the SharedPreferences  , follow these steps :

```
SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences = PreferenceManager .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
```

**To get value :**

```
boolean mCheckBoxValue = mSharedPreferences .getBoolean("CheckBox_Value", false);
```

**to Save value**

```
boolean value= true;
Editor mEditor = mSharedPreferences .edit();
mEditor.putBoolean("CheckBox_Value", value);
mEditor.commit();
```

read more details on Android developer page 
[Saving Key-Value Sets](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html)

Comment: Thank for your reply, I see it, but I don't know how integrate these parameters into the code, especially for the loading part. I try some actions without success :-(

Comment: look at this example , its very simple :D

----http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/content/android-sharedpreferences-example/